# Getting access to recording device name's label in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, recording

I need to read the name of the recording device displayed in Windows properties,  sound->recording devices. Following my example, It's Realtek High Definition Audio (I guess It actually is It's controller name).
If windows displays It, there must be WinAPI function to determine It. 
I have done some google research about It, but with no particular success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This varies with the version of Windows you want to imitate. Up through Windows XP, the control panel undoubtedly showed DirectSound devices. Displaying them is fairly simple and straightforward:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <dsound.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dsound.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

BOOL CALLBACK sound_capture_callback(LPGUID, LPCSTR description, LPCSTR, void *) {
    std::cout << description << "\n";
    return true;
}

int main() { 
    DWORD ignore;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    DirectSoundCaptureEnumerate(sound_capture_callback, (void*)&ignore);    
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Starting with Windows 7 (or maybe Vista--don't remember for sure) Microsoft added what they call Media Foundation. This is conceptually somewhat similar, but a bit more complex. The sequence goes something like this:

1. You start with `MFCreateAttributes` to create a Media Foundation attributes COM object.
2. You use that object's `SetGuid` member to tell it to enumerate sound (rather than video) devices.
3. You call `MFEnumDeviceSources` to actually enumerate the devices. 
   That gets you pointers to `IMFActivate` interfaces.
4. You call `GetAllocatedString` on each interface (passing `MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME`) to get the name of the device.

In the latter case, the usual warning for COM applies. COM itself is an over-engineered mess, and Media Foundation tries to maximize that concept. It's essentially unavoidable that code to enumerate MF devices will be at least 3 times longer and 5 times harder to understand than the code above for DirectSound. If you're making serious use of MF, you'll almost certainly want to create some wrappers to isolate this ugliness, but you can't really get rid of it, and for a small task like enumerating devices, you probably won't reduce it either.